# haskell appending lists and recursion

Tags: haskell, recursion

In haskell I want to write code which will do the following using recursion:
1. compare first 2 elements if x is less than y then append y then recursively do the comparison else append x and do the recursion again.

I did like this:

```
f:: [Int] -> [Int]
f(x:[]) = [x]
f(x:y:xs)
    | x <= y    = y:f xs
    | otherwise = x:f xs
```

but this will do append after taking next 2 elements, i want to append before passing to recursion. But below didn't work as compiler seems to be passing first element for recursion and then the list hence compilation errors.

```
f(x:[]) = [x]
f(x:y:xs)
    | x <= y    = f y:xs
    | otherwise = f x:xs
```

How shall i append the element to the list before passing to next recursion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue you appear to be having is a precedence problem.

When you have the following expression.

```
f y:xs
```

It is treated by the compiler as the following.

```
(f y) : xs
```

You can see this in action in the error message, where it actually refers to the first arguement of `:` as being `f y` rather than just `y`.

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘Int’ with actual type ‘[Int]’
In the first argument of ‘(:)’, namely ‘f y’
In the expression: f y : xs
```

In this case the fix is easy. You just need to specially note that the `:` operation should be applied and its result passed into the call to `f`.

To do this, you just need to wrap it in parentheses.

```
f (y:xs)
```